# C# .NET Regex 'Unrecognized escape sequence'

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate a password field using regex under the namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions but I'm getting three errors for

> 'Unrecognized escape sequence'.

When I double click on the errors it highlights the '-' in my expression for the character range but I don't know why this is wrong.

// password must contain one uppercase, one lowercase and one digit

```
Regex reg = new Regex("^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+`~\[\]{}?|])(?=.+[a-z])(?=.+[A-Z])(? =.+[0-9]).{8,50}$");
```

Comment: You are missing a `@` before the regex literal.

Comment: You should escape \ character.

Comment: Why have you specified a maximum length for the password? Please, never do that.

Comment: Duplicate talks about paths, but it's the same \ character/lack of @ causing the problem.

Comment: it seems `(? =.+[0-9]).{8,50}` here you have one space after  `?` it should not be

Answer (score 5):

Just add an `@` before the first quote to make it a verbatim string literal or escape the backslashes as `\\`.

Answer (score -1):

it seems you have one space after `?`

> (? =.+[0-9]).{8,50}

remove that.